# Python Help: Creating a dict of {str:list of str} from csv file

Tags: python, import-from-csv

I have to create a table in the format: `{str: list of str}`

Opening a .csv file using the following code, I get:

```
import csv
cr = csv.reader(open("name.csv","r"))
for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

output:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
['value4', 'value5', 'value6']
```

I essentially need to structure this into the format

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value4'], 'key2': ['value2', 'value5'], 'key3': ['value3', 'value6']}
```

I'm stuck; I just can't think of a way to do this for it to work for any number of keys and values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip()` to turn rows into columns, then make those into dictionary keys and values:

```
import csv

with open("name.csv", newline='') as infh:
    cr = csv.reader(infh)
    columns = {r[0]: list(r[1:]) for r in zip(*cr)}
```

A quick demo of the last line:

```
>>> cr = [
...     ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
...     ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
...     ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'],
... ]
>>> {r[0]: list(r[1:]) for r in zip(*cr)}
{'key3': ['value3', 'value6'], 'key2': ['value2', 'value5'], 'key1': ['value1', 'value4']}
```

where `cr` stands in for the `csv.reader()` object.

`zip(*iterable)` takes all elements in an iterable and transforms it like a matrix; columns become rows as each nested value is paired up with values from the other rows at the same position:

```
>>> zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

and the dict comprehension `{key_expression: value_expression for targets in iterable}` produces a dictionary, where in the above code each first element in a column becomes the key, and the rest forms the value.

Comment: Just to note, on Python 2.6 and below, just replace the last line with `columns = dict(zip(r[0], list(r[1:]) for r in zip(*cr)))`. I've deleted my answer and upvoted this one because I misunderstood the question in my haste to answer.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: Because the OP is using `print()` as a function, I think we can assume that we are looking at Python 3 here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but how would i return the value from the above code in the python shell? i used your code but when i add: print(cr) it returns: <_csv.reader object at 0x02EC59B0> also, your demo used a list of lists so i couldn't really apply it to my problem.

Comment: `columns` is your result, not `cr`. :-) The demo input is otherwise functionally equivalent of what `cr` produces when looped over.

Comment: One more thing, this code is basically suppose to go into my function but my function takes a file that's already open for reading meaning that the user has already typed: c = csv.reader(open('file.csv','r')). now that messes up the with open(table,newline = '') as infh. How would i make it so it does what it does already without it opening again? also, what is infh?

Comment: `infh` is just the local name for the file object ("input file handle"). You can use any open file object for the `csv.reader()` object, you don't *have* to use the `with open() as ..` line.

Comment: thank you so much :). Sad to say I've been at this problem for the past 7 hours...